# window.addEventListener("message", getData); doesn't work in safari?

Tags: javascript, safari, postmessage

I am sending a postmessage from js script to iframe which is in react

// listensting to postMessage() function in react
// React File

```
useEffect(() => {

function getData(e) {
  console.log("inside function");
  var origin = e.origin || e.originalEvent.origin;
  console.log("origin", origin);

  if (typeof e.data == "object" && "shopDomain" in e.data) {
    console.log(e.data);
  } else {
    console.log("not able to catch data");
  }
}
window.addEventListener("message", getData, false);
return () => {
  window.removeEventListener("message", getData, false);
};
}, []);
```

// JS File

```
let win = iframe.contentWindow;
win.contentWindow.postMessage(
  {
    customerId: customerId_rs,
    parentLocation: window.location.host,
  },
  "*"
);
```

Looked at various sites but can't find any solution. Have spent almost 10 hours at this any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like safari dont have the full support but it should support if you check the browser support of `addEventListener` you can see

- options.passive parameter defaults to true for touchstart and touchmove events
- options.passive parameter defaults to true for wheel and mousewheel events
- options.signal parameter

these *do not have support*. you can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#browser_compatibility)

Comment: It supports I'm successfully able to send postMessage from my react to JS file. But I'm not able to do the opposite . I'm missing something